# compact and expanded jQuery pop-up dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-dialog

I'm totally new in MVC, I have info that I show in a jQuery pop-up dialog, but I need to compact and expand this dialog, as a small dialog has glance about my info, and a button when I click it expands to show all info, and click again to compact.
My project is in MVC 4.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I think you are speaking about the jQuery toogle functionality. Here i paste below a small demo. Hope it may help you.

```
**Html code**
 <button type="button" id ="clickme" >Click Me!</button> 
<div id ="toggleSection">
   Toggle content here ...!
</div>

**Jquery Code** 
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#toggleSection" ).toggle( "slow", function() {

  });
});
```

Comment: thank you,it's the same idea,but i need it exactly as dialog :)

Comment: because i have many partial views in the same view,when i click on one of them it must pop-up separately.